# Launching FireFox 39 by configuring its profile

Tags: firefox, selenium, jenkins, selenium-rc

I launch this commande :
`java -jar "D:/FTP/stm_atos_automatisation/selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar" 
-trustAllSSLCertificates -userExtensions "D:/FTP/stm_atos_automatisation/user-extensions.js" -htmlSuite "*firefox D:/FTP/stm_atos_automatisation/navigateurs/ff39/firefox.exe" 
"https://zed330z7:59443/stm_ihm/" "D:/FTP/stm_atos_automatisation/Suites/Serveur/Total_Courbes.htm" "D:/FTP/stm_atos_automatisation/rapports/ff39/rapport.html"`

and the FireFox start but it stops because two SSL3 are added in the version 39.I desactive manually the two SSL3 and the FireFox continue .

I want to automate this desactivation by configuring its profile.Can you please give me the method to follow ?

After, I will launch the same test from Jenkins.

Thanks in Advance

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I assume by *"two SSL3 are added"* you mean the `security.ssl3.<...>` cryptographic algorithms entries of FF's `about:config`.

FF's preferences are stored in `<FF profile>/prefs.js.` Add (if it doesn't exist) or adapt (if it does) a line like:

```
user_pref("security.ssl3.ecdhe_ecdsa_aes_128_gcm_sha256", false);
```